# Text from php variable into javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am using a jquery calendar that looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#calendar').eCalendar({

 weekDays: ['Dim', 'Lun', 'Mar', 'Mer', 'Jeu', 'Ven', 'Sam'],
    months: ['Janvier', 'Fevrier', 'Mars', 'Avril', 'Mai', 'Juin', 'Juillet', 'Aout', 'Septembre', 'Octobre', 'Novembre', 'Decembre'],
    textArrows: {previous: '<', next: '>'},
    eventTitle: 'Evenements',
    url: '',

    events: [

   { title: 'title', description: 'description', datetime: new Date (2015,07,01)} 


    ]});
});
</script>
```

To get the events, I connect to a mysql database and store the result in a php variable such as:

```
 $event={ title: 'title', description: 'description', datetime: new Date:   (2015,07,01)};
```

I can't figure out how to put this $event into the jquery script so that it reads it.

I tried for exemple:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#calendar').eCalendar({
    ........
    ........
    events: [

   <?php echo $event ?>

    ]});
});
```

Which doesn't work. Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: if ```$event``` has the correct value, it should work. Can you post the output of your browser in the question (source code)?

Comment: is **$event** a __string__ or an __array__? (the php one)

Comment: did you try to add quotes like this `'<?php echo $event ?>'`?

Comment: It should work, IF $event IS A **STRING**. Otherwise, you have to stringify it.

Comment: try `<?php echo json_encode($event); ?>`

Comment: You should do this with ajax, but $event should be a string formatted exactly like you would do in plain javascript;

Comment: maybe the structure of the events should be a javascript array instead of json? provide us a link of the calendar you use

Comment: 1- verify the formating of events array as per needed in .eCalender in Jquery
2- Its better to bring $events in json format and then here decode
3- First try to put manually a string or an array to just check the calender

Answer (score 1):

You have to be sure that $event is a string.
I bet it is an array, please provide a `vardump($event);`to be sure of that.

If it is an array, try this in place of `<?php echo $event; ?>;`:

> `<?php echo serialize($event); ?>;`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the problem is an error, excess colon after `new Date`:

`$event="{ title: 'title', description: 'description', datetime: new Date: (2015,07,01)};"`